# File /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Versions/A/Support/accountsd

Tags: mail.app, email, password

Im using Mac Mini 2016 with macOS 10.13.2.

**Problem**
My antivirus software, Sophos, identifies malicious traffic from */System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Versions/A/Support/accountsd* when Im trying to change password for one of mine email accounts in email client Mac Mail. In essence password can´t be changed due to "*can´t verify account username and password*".

**Print screen**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/esvshj8n01acl9z/Malicious%20traffic.png?dl=0

**Tried solutions**
I have tried to whitelist */System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Versions/A/Support/accountsd* in the antivirus software but the problem doesn´t go away.

I have also tried to change the password for the same email account in a different mail client (Thunderbird). It worked.

**Questions**
1) What is */System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Versions/A/Support/accountsd* for?
2) Why is it messing with email password changes in Mac Mail?
3) How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
J